# About a notation of automorphisms between groups

Tags: group-theory, notation, group-isomorphism

In my homework, an excercise started with the following:

Let $$\alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2) \in Aut(K \times H)$$ (K and H are groups).

My question: shouldn't that be $$ \alpha = (\alpha_1, \alpha_2) \in Aut(K \times H) \times Aut(K \times H)$$?

Later on in the exercise the phrases $\alpha_1(h, k), \alpha_2(h, k)$ appear, so I don't understand how can $\alpha$ be a pair of automorphisms and also an automorphism itself...

Any idea what does it mean? Or is it just a typo of the exercise makers?

Comment: This is simply saying that $\alpha_1$ is the $K$-coordinate of $\alpha$,and $\alpha_2$ is the $H$-coordinate

Comment: You mean that $\alpha(k, h) = (\alpha_1(k), \alpha_2(h))$?

Comment: No, $\alpha (k,h) =(\alpha_1 (k,h), \alpha_2 (k,h))$

Comment: Ohhh OK I got it. Silly me. Thx!